# get or post within ActionCable tests in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using a JWT to authenticate my user.

So when a user want to connect to the ActionCable server, it does something like this:

- Get a JWT from REST endpoint: POST /users/sign_in
- Establish a ws to ActionCable using this jwt.

```js
// Establish connection
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/websocket?token="+jwt)
```

I want to test this connection so I'm using what is in Rails 6 out of the box:

```rb
# test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
require "test_helper"

class ApplicationCable::ConnectionTest < ActionCable::Connection::TestCase

  test "connects with jwt" do
    post "/users/sign_in", params: { user: {email: "123@ok.com", password: "ok"}}, as: :json
    token  = response.headers["Authorization"]
    connect params: { token: token }
    assert_equal connection.user_id, "1"
  end

end
```

But i have the following error:

```
Error:
ApplicationCable::ConnectionTest#test_connects_with_jwt:
NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for #<ApplicationCable::ConnectionTest:0x0000555bbab0ecb0>
    test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:ConnectionTest>
```

What should I do to be able to perform this `post` to my controller ?
Thanks!

BONUS: if I can use routes prefixes, i.e. `user_session_url` instead of `"/users/sign_in"` it's better!

Comment: This is exactly what's driving me made for 2 hours now! Did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: You are sending `POST` request to the controller I suppose you should use `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` instead of `ActionCable::Connection::TestCase`

Answer (score 0):

You can pull in all of the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` goodies by including `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest::Behavior` in your test class.

I haven't tested this with `ActionCable::Connection::TestCase`, but I'm using it with my channel tests like this:

```
require "test_helper"

class FoosChannelTest < ActionCable::Channel::TestCase
  include ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest::Behavior
  tests FoosChannel

  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  describe "when a new Foo is created" do
    it "broadcasts an event to the user channel" do
      post foos_path, params: {
        foo: {
          name: "Foo1",
        }
      }, as: :json

      assert_broadcasts user, 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this https://relishapp.com/palkan/action-cable-testing/docs
(the same code can be used with Requests specs)

```
RSpec.describe CommentsController do
  describe "POST #create" do
    expect { post :create, comment: { text: 'Cool!' } }.to
      have_broadcasted_to("comments").with(text: 'Cool!')
  end
end
```

don't forget to disable background jobs (in case of delayed jobs, add `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false`)